# Issues with lenght mis-match when fitting model on categorical variables using xgb classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I trained a model which has several categorical variables which I encoded using dummies from pandas. Now, when I score the model on new/unseen data, I have lesser categorical variables than in the train dataset. Thus, I get a mis-match error.

Instead of using pd.dummies, is there a better best practice so account for different distinct values for a categorical feature between train and validation dataset?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

One advantage to using [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in `sklearn.preprocessing` is that it will create the same number of dummy features in the test data as is in the training data, regardless of whether that category is present in the test set or not.  Pandas `getdummies` will not do this, so it will produce a mismatch in categories if not all categories are present in the test set.

There is an informative article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-using-pandas-get-dummies-for-feature-encoding-5d2cd07cb4fc) on the topic.